# Why my matrix inverse implementation is less accurate? C++

Tags: c++, eigen, matrix-inverse, transformation-matrix

I have a transformation matrix of type Eigen::Matrix4d. And I would like to get its inverse. I write a function my self to compute it by the following formular.

[image].

And here is my code:

```
Eigen::Matrix4d inverseTransformation(Eigen::Matrix4d T)
{
    Eigen::MatrixX3d R;
    Eigen::Vector3d t;
    R = T.block<3, 3>(0, 0);
    t = T.block<3, 1>(0, 3);
    Eigen::Matrix4d result;
    result.setIdentity();
    result.block<3, 3>(0, 0) = R.transpose();
    result.block<3, 1>(0, 3) = -R.transpose() * t;
    return result;
}



    std::cout<<"Input transformation matrix is:\n" << T << std::endl;
    std::cout << "inverse of T , my implementation:\n" << inverseTransformation(T) << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "inverse of T , Eigen implementation::\n" << T.inverse() << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "T * T^(-1), my implementation\n " << T * inverseTransformation(T) << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "T * T^(-1), eigen's implementation\n " << T * T.inverse() << std::endl << std::endl;
```

Ideally, T * T^(1) should be I. However, there is some error in my result (the red part in the following picture.)

[image]

By contrast, the result from T * T.inverse() is much more accurate.

Could someone please tell me why? Thanks a lot in advance!

Update:
Inverse of a rotation matrix is its transpose. The result will be more accurate if I replace R.tranpose() with R.inverse().

Comment: It has to do with floating point precission, which is not that precise. There are complete univeristy courses on how to minimize errors in outcomes devoted to this. But it all starts here : [is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: in general, differnt algorithms yield different results with different precision, that should not be a surprise. Consider you would have a solution only accurate up to 2 digits, then you could use the result of `T * T.inverse()` to improve the result, you could do this iteratively to get incrementally better precision. Now it only depends at what point you stop that iteration. And eventually you are limited by precision of `double`

Comment: According to the formula you posted, The top left part of the matrix should be R^(-1) (i.e. R inverse), not R transposed as done your code. Same goes regarding -R^(-1)*d.

Comment: @wohlstad Maybe `R` is a rotation matrix, whose inverse is equal to its transpose. But it would be good if this were clarified in the question.

Comment: @Thomas I see, missed that. I believe these lines of code should have a comment stating that, for clarity.

Comment: @wohlstad, Hi I just added that in the question. And I found that If I use R.inverse() instead of R.transpose(), the result will be much more accurate. Now I believe that the rotation matrix expressed in the floating system is not accurate enough. Hence, I cannot replace R.inverse() with R.transpose()

Comment: @PepijnKramer Hi, thank you for your hint. That makes sense. Theoretically, R.inverse() equals to R.tranpose(). But this is not correct in floating point system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments. Since I would like to close this question, I will answer it my self.

Theoretically, R.inverse() equals to R.tranpose(). But this is not correct in floating point system. Once I use R.inverse(), the result is more accurate.